# Android inputstream IOException - large file Android 2.2

Tags: android, inputstream, ioexception, assets

Hi i am getting an IOException running my application using Android 2.2. I dont get that when I use Android 2.3.

I am trying to copy a pdf file (size 1.6MB) from assets folder to the internal storage of the application using the following block of code.

```
 1. private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
 2.    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 3.    int read;
 4.    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
 5.      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
 6.     }
 7. }
```

I am getting the IOException when I execute line 4.

It runs without any exception in the following cases
 - When I use small file (size 320kb)
 - When I build it as Android 2.3 project.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue? If size is a problem, is there a work around for that?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Navin

Comment: Which IOException? That is, what's the message attached to it? That'll give more information about what's going on.